# How fast is fast enough for your unit tests to run all the time?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

At some point the speed of your unit tests will be fast enough to run them all the time, and notify you of any failures as you develop.

How fast is fast enough?

Answer (score 2):

In Java in eclipse I don't run my whole test suite all the time. I tend to run the set of tests in a single test class that I'm editing. Only once I'm done will I run the whole suite, and always before commit.

In c# in Visual Studio on the other hand I use a continuous tester called [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/). It has the ability to be configured to run all tests on code change or just those impacted since the last run. This second feature is very useful when you start to get a large test suite.

Answer (score 1):

Fast enough that as soon as a new failure occurs you are aware of it.  But not so fast so that you are being spammed with notifications of the failure over and over again while you are developing.

Generally, you aren't going to have your tests running "all the time".  Rather after every change in your code the tests are rerun.  If nothing has been changed there really isn't any point in re-running your tests because you already know the results of the tests.

The speed of the tests should be enough that you aren't having your development flow broken by the running of the tests.  So that you don't have to wait and surf SO for your tests to finish and then try to remember what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post on Games From Within](http://gamesfromwithin.com/whats-your-pain-threshold) it is about two seconds. It also details how they got them to a lot less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a matter of personal feeling, but above 10 seconds is when I start to feel uncomfortable and hampered in my flow (realized afterwards this has been noticed [by others](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/05/24/TDDtestsuitesshouldrunin10secondsorless/) too).

A smart test runner, i.e. one that doesn't run tests unaffected by changes + runs tests most likely to fail first is a good help.

I also found out continuous testing (NCrunch) made my programming experience much more fluid since you don't have to go through the moves of launching test runs all the time. Only having to keep an eye on an occasional red bar frees your mind a lot.